# How do I prevent pip automatically installing supporting packages?

Tags: python, matplotlib, pip

I am using python 3.6.0 within a venv. I would like to "pip install" matplotlib==2.0.0, however when I do this, pip seems to automatically grab the newest versions of all other required supporting packages for matplotlib. i.e. cycler 0.11.0, pyparsing==3.0.7, etc. These latest supporting package versions do not seem to work with the older version of matplotlib and it throws errors when attempting to import matplotlib.

How do I install matplotlib without pip attempting to install all its supporting packages automatically?

My current temporary solution is to go back and manually install each package before installing matplotlib but I'm sure I will run into this issue again so would like to find a better solution.

Comment: You could a requirements file with the old requirements and matplotlib 2.00 at the end, so its just a single install step. `pip install -r my-matplotlib-requirements-file`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pip has a built-in feature:

`pip install matplotlib --no-dependencies`

To exclude specific, you can put it in requirements file and pass it:

`pip install --no-deps -r requirements.txt`